# How to send the product data (from table) when "Add to Cart" is clicked to My cart page?

Tags: database, jsp, servlets

I'm working on a small 'Shopping Site' college project...I had created everything but stucked at one Problem.

There is a content part aligned center in my page where i have a table for Product name,Price and Add to cart in consecutive rows...

```
<div id="Content">
 <table id="ContentTable">
      <tr> 
        <td id="iphone5"><img class="thumbnail" src="mobile_img/iphone-5.jpg"></td>
        <td><img class="thumbnail" src="mobile_img/Lumia-920.jpg">  </td>
        <td><img class="thumbnail" src="mobile_img/blackberry-curve-9300.jpg">  </td>
        <td><img class="thumbnail" src="mobile_img/header.jpg">  </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>$ 5767435</td>
        <td> $ 2343456</td>
        <td> $ 123123</td>
        <td>$ 345345</td>
     </tr>

      <tr class="productdetails"> 
        <td><a href="My Cart.jsp">Add to my cart</a></td>
        <td><a href="My Cart.jsp">Add to my cart</td></a>
        <td><a href="">Add to my cart</td></a>
        <td><a href="">Add to my cart</td></a>
      </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Problem is that, how could i attach product details to 'Add to cart' link below them and send them to other page, which is to be stored in database when 'Add to Cart' below them is clicked...

Comment: Please avoid space in filenames in websites... this is not a good practice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can make a seperate table in database containing the item id,item name or link to the image (or any other way to store images), and the price.
in the page where you want to display, pull the values from the database and put it in a form. so that it would look like:

```
<form name="something" action="Add_to_Cart.jsp" method="post">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="<%item_id%>"></td>
<td><%Image link/item name 1%></td>
<td><%price 1%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="<%item_id%>"></td>
<td><%Image link/item name 2%></td>
<td><%price 2%></td>
</tr>
.
.
.
```

and finally at the end a submit button with showing Add to Cart..

```
<input type="submit" name="Getthis" value="Add to Cart"/>
</form>
```

and then retrive the values like this

```
String items[]= request.getParameterValues("item");
```

look for reference: http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/jsp/multiplecheckbox.html

so now you will have the id's of the item selected and can easily add to cart..
(ps. the codes are just snippets)

Comment: Oh right , i have done a stupidity by adding 'href' to a 'Add to cart', it has to be in a forms submit button.
Thanks, will try and post back.

Comment: if answer is ever helpful then help me by up-voting or accepting the answer... although it a matter of your personal satisfaction..